# Android Device Monitor - Failed to create the java virtual machine

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, jvm, virtual-device-manager

I am trying to use the Android Device Monitor tool.

I am using windows 10, **Android studio 1.5**, I get this error -

Failed to Create the Java virtual Machine.

Please help.

Comment: Is there anything else to the stacktrace? Often that's a sign that more memory (heap) is needed than can be obtained.

Comment: Nope, android studio log cat didn't have any error or any thing logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below file to modify vm heap option.

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions
```

Increase **-Xms128m to -Xms512m** (your default set value) and restart Android Studio.

Hope this helps.